# Joomla - Page Builder - With Publish Workflow

Tags: joomla-3.x, workflow

We have recently built a site on Joomla and have used the SP Page Builder. But unfortunately, the SP Page Builder does not have the Workflow / User Access mechanism where one set of users create the content / page and other set of users preview it and publish. Are there any other alternative Page Builder plugins that provide this functionality?

Many Thanks

Comment: Did you mean you want a allow a user to submit content, then an editor review it, and then a publisher publish it?

Comment: Yes, thats right. But with SP Page Builder, looks it is not possible. In fact, I have seen many page builders, none of them provide this workflow.

Comment: Please take our [tour], then have a look at: https://www.joomlashack.com/blog/tutorials/joomla-4-workflows/ and [Joomla! 4.0 - new publishing workflow - Benjamin Trenkle](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=5e-HECq44B0), and [Joomla 4 custom fields and workflow](https://www.timplummer.com.au/54-joomla-4-custom-fields-and-workflow) and Tim's presentation video at https://youtu.be/-MSkF_TC1ko

Answer (score 0):

This extension offers workflow in wait for Joomla 4:
https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/swjprojects/

Comment: Sorry, wrong link, try this 
https://joomflows.com/

Comment: Bjorn, please [edit] your answer to replace your recommended hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension for your workflow management.
It's available for J3 and J4.

https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/clients-a-communities/project-a-task-management/joomproject/